# Having pcase conditions do nothing

Tags: pcase

Is it possible to make some of the `pcase` conditions do nothing?  How can I do this if possible?

Comment: What do you mean with 'do nothing'? And why do you want to include these cases in the pcase definition?

Comment: I am working on the basic design, for the details to be completed later, some likely to be done by others.

Comment: Each clause is of the form `(PATTERN BODY-FORMS)`, so I expect that if you have just the pattern in the clause with no body-forms, then nothing will happen when that pattern matches.

Comment: You can just put nil or something in the body.  It doesn't have to *do* anything more than return a value.