# Setting numeric value associated with symbol

Tags: conditionals

I have the following condition to set `mbcomplt` according to the symbol stored in `armg`.  Is there a more convenient way (e.g a shorter way of setting `mbcomplt`) to set the numeric value for `mbcomplt` associated with symbol.

```
  (defvar armgv 0)
  (defvar cia '(norm norm))

  (defun mbcomplt-authentis (cookie)
     "DOC."

   (let ( (armg (car cookie))
          (seqr (car (cdr cookie))) )
  
     (cond
      ((eq armg 'auto)
          (setq mbcomplt 0))
      ((eq armg 'icomplt-horz)
          (setq mbcomplt 1))
      ((eq armg 'icomplt-vert)
          (setq mbcomplt 2))
      ((eq armg 'ivy)
          (setq mbcomplt 3))
      ((eq armg 'vertico)
          (setq mbcomplt 4))
      ((eq armg 'helm)
          (setq mbcomplt 5)))))
```

Comment: When posting code, please make an effort to ensure that it is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sets `mbcomplt` to a number `1` to `5` depending on the value of the variable `armg` (which is supposed to be a symbol like `'ivy`).  A more efficient way to do the same thing is this:

```lisp
    (setq mbcomplt
      (cl-case armg
        ('auto 0)
        ('icomplt-horz 1)
        ('icomplt-vert 2)
        ('ivy 3)
        ('vertico 4)
        ('helm 5)))
```

You can do something similar with `cond`: the point is that conditionals in lisp are expressions that return a value.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain on use of symbols and values?  Here you set `mbcomplt`, but need assistance on the meaning of the rest and how to use them.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking here.  Are you asking how `cl-case` works?  (If so, do `C-h f cl-case`).  Or are you asking how evaluation works in emacs-lisp, in which case you should read an introduction to emacs-lisp ( `C-h R eintr`).

Comment: Am asking how I would be using your construct.  If I want to set `mbcomplt` to symbol `auto` with value `0`, what would I do.  I would then have to check whether an argument passed to a function is `auto` and then use it value, according to value, then do something.

Comment: How can I set a `symbol` and set a value to it?

Comment: I am not sure you understand what your original code does.  I have edited my answer to make things a bit clearer.  However, I have no idea what you mean by "How can I set a `symbol` and set a value to it?"

Comment: Have seen things like `symbol-value`.  Perhaps using this has no purpose for this case.  When one sets a symbol to a variable.  Could that symbol also include a value besides the symbol name?

Comment: Ok, you compare `armg` against each symbol key, then set the numeric value.

Comment: Correct: this is exactly what the `cond` expression in your post did.

Comment: You can also use [pcase](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/pcase-Macro.html) so that you do not require 'cl-lib'. But I guess that [you knew about that](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74301/having-pcase-conditions-do-nothing) already.